# How to find out devices associated as iMessage client with my apple ID

Tags: ios, messages

Is it possible to find out what devices have been registered to receive iMessage with my Apple ID?

I can only see my phone number and Apple ID in iMessage settings, but not what devices are registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Itunes > Itunes Store > Click on email id after logging in (i.e. view account) > Manage Devices

That should get you a list of devices, that you have your appleid enabled on. You can check those device settings to see if iMessage is enabled and if yes, under what ID.

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for, but solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see 'Manage Devices' there. It seems that it's a huge security leak in Apple's devices.

Comment: [apple's specific instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT205064)
here's [another link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204074)

Comment: That shows you who is logged on to your iCloud account, but that’s not necessarily the same as the list of devices signed on to iMessage or FaceTime. You can be logged in to one and not the other.